# Ensure that docker is using device-mapper storage backend

Tags: docker

Docker 0.7 introduces multiple storage backends, and one of them is `devicemapper`. How can I check which storage backend it is using, and force it to use `devicemapper` if it is not already?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To check which one it is currently using:

```
sudo docker info|grep 'Storage Driver:'
```

You can force docker to use `devicemapper` by adding `-s=devicemapper` to the docker daemon's command line arguments (the docker daemon will be run as a service on boot, so this will involve modifying a file in `/etc`, probably `/etc/default/docker`, or if that doesn't exist, `/etc/sysconfig/docker`).

Comment: That's `DOCKER_OPTS="--storage-driver=devicemapper"` in the configuration file -- http://muehe.org/posts/switching-docker-from-aufs-to-devicemapper/